# How to display select dropdown on rollover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-select

Would it be possible to display the  dropdown options on select rollover using javascript/jquery? I have took a look at http://www.devcurry.com/2009/04/using-javascript-to-dropdown-html.html but the demo doesn't appear to function 100% properly.

Comment: Yes, that is possible. If you want help with doing it, please try some things yourself and if you get stuck, post the details and we'll try to help you out.

Comment: What part of the demo does not work for you ?

Comment: I have to push for more details on expected functionality. Are you wanting to avoid the displacement of other elements?